# pandas merge dataframes different line count repeat data

Tags: python, pandas, merge, repeat

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) that I want to merge. I want to have price and a code for every row in `df1` . How can I merge these so that the price and code repeats itself and lines up based on the fruit? I believe that I need to set the fruit as the index in order to do this?

`df1 =`

```
fruit grown    farm
    apple   fruit ranch
    banana  fresh grow
    grapes  paradise lake
    melon   country hills
    cherry  paradise lake
    orange  paradise lake
    apple   fruit ranch
    apple   paradise lake
    cherry  fresh grow
    grapes  fruit ranch
    apple   country hills
    melon   paradise lake
    cherry  fruit ranch
    orange  fresh grow
```

`df2 =`

```
fruit   price   code
apple    3      568
banana   2      426
grapes   4      112
melon    6      368
cherry   1      569
orange   4      775
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to merge them using `pandas.DataFrame.merge`, but you may want to change the column name first before being able to merge them.

```py
df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'fruit':'fruit grown'}), how='left')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
   fruit grown           farm  price  code
0        apple    fruit ranch      3   568
1       banana     fresh grow      2   426
2       grapes  paradise lake      4   112
3        melon  country hills      6   368
4       cherry  paradise lake      1   569
5       orange  paradise lake      4   775
6        apple    fruit ranch      3   568
7        apple  paradise lake      3   568
8       cherry     fresh grow      1   569
9       grapes    fruit ranch      4   112
10       apple  country hills      3   568
11       melon  paradise lake      6   368
12      cherry    fruit ranch      1   569
13      orange     fresh grow      4   775
```

Comment: When I try that I am getting a MergeError 'No common columns to perform merge on'. I think this is because in df1 the column for fruit is 'fruit grown' and is different than the 'fruit' column in df2

Comment: @Kevin, see the updated answer, that's because the data sample you have in the question somehow seems to be mis-aligned